# How to add IPv6 routing header to UDP and/or TCP packet in JAVA?

Tags: java, ipv6, packet

I want to send IPv6 packets from server to client through a specific router. That's why I want to add Routing Header, which contains th address of specific router.

Does anyone know, how can I add Routing Header to a packet in JAVA?

Answer (score 4):

My library may help you. This is a java library for crafting and sending packets.
https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me, how could I install it easily on Win7?

Comment: You need pcap4j.jar, jna.jar, slf4j-api.jar, and WinPcap at least. Each are available from below.

  * pcap4j.jar: https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/downloads

  * slf4j.api.jar: http://slf4j.org/download.html

  * jna.jar: https://github.com/twall/jna

  * WinPcap: http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm

  After installation WinPcap, try the following command: `java -cp pcap4j.jar;jna-3.3.0.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar org.pcap4j.sample.Loop`

  If you can capture packets by the above command, you are ready to develop your application with Pcap4j.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Most routers ignore this sort of information for security reasons (see [RFC 5095](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5095.txt) to know why), and Java doesn't support changing or inspecting header information.

Comment: That's not so good information for me. I'm writing my thesis, including a java client-server application, which test difference between native IPv6 and tunneled IPv6 connection. Should send packets through the tunnel endpoint, that's why I want to change 
routing header.

Do you know any programming language, what support this?

Comment: The programming language doesn't matter. It's the network equipment that will ignore or block the routing header...